# Foreach loop using $wpdb not results from rows

Tags: wpdb

I'm using `$wpdb` to develop a plugin to check for some row fields to see if they match and echo true or false.
My original code was working when it was a separate mysql DB and accessed that way.
As its within wordpress plugin i needed to use `$wpdb`.

Im selecting from a separate table ( ipn_data_tbl ) and the wpdb prefix gets appended correctly.
I want to check each row in that table and match where the item_name and payer_email are check from a software that gets activated.
It all worked on stand alone DB outside of wordpress but now i've added the $wpdb (incorrectly?) its not working.

I don't think i am using it correct..any ideas? :

```
<?php



require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
    $ipn_table = $wpdb->prefix ."ipn_data_tbl";


   global $wpdb,$ipONactivate,$ipn_table;



$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$ipn_table` WHERE `item_name` = '$product' && `payer_email` = '$serial'";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql)or die(mysql_error());  //$wpdb->get_results

    if ($result->num_rows != 0) {
        foreach($result as $row){

        if ($row[`item_name`] == $product && $row[`payer_email`] == $serial) {
            echo true;
             } else {
            echo false;
                    }
                }
            }

?>
```

Comment: What do `$product` and `$serial` variables contain?

Comment: The software being activated sends the software title and email to this script which also uses the Slim framework and if it matches the 'same' from new table in WP database sends an echo back to the software..if it matches echo's true and software is activated, if false says not activated and to contact support. it works outside of WordPress..im trying to bring it into wordpress simple plugin to make it easier and have no need to create a separate DB in cpanel and use a connect.php file.
Here is original file->  https://pastebin.com/embed_js/tYapfAw6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should never concatenate SQL Query with any variables this way - it will cause SQL Injection vulnerability.

Also... `get_results` method returns just an array of results. You can’t use it as an object and get `num_rows` from it - there is no such property in an array (it’s a property of `WPDB` object).

Another problem is that by default `get_results` will return selected rows in object format, not as arrays.

So here’s the fixed code:

```
<?php
    require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

    global $wpdb, $ipONactivate;

    $ipn_table = $wpdb->prefix ."ipn_data_tbl";

    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM {$ipn_table} WHERE item_name = %s AND payer_email = %s",
        $product, $serial
    ) );

    if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
        foreach($result as $row) {

            if ($row->item_name == $product && $row->payer_email == $serial) {
                echo true;
            } else {
                echo false;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

BTW. You can trust the SQL. If you select only rows that has given product and serial, then you don’t have to loop through them and check if they are equal to given values.

Comment: Thanks Krzysiek..i had an obvious typo i didnt see. I copy/pasted your coode but had to add a bit more..but got it going. Thanks again..you ROCK mate :)

Comment: @Schmutly yeah, I’m pretty sure it’s just a simplified version of what you needed in the end - it was meant to show the idea how to loop through these results